# Google charts issue showing only 1 option

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I am able to see only one option `['Pend']` but `['Attend']` option is not showing from the chart, what is the issue from my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
function drawChart() {  
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
        ['Pend', 'Attended'],  
        <?php  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
             echo "['".$row['Pend']."', '".$row['Attended']."'],";  
        }  
        ?>  
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the second value in the array should be a number, not a string.
remove the single quotes...

change...

```
echo "['".$row['Pend']."', '".$row['Attended']."'],";
```

to...

```
echo "['".$row['Pend']."', ".$row['Attended']."],";
```

Comment: not working still, this is my query ```SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PointsArchieved=0 AND Extrapoints=0 AND Finalpoint=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pend, SUM(CASE WHEN PointsArchieved=0 AND Extrapoints=0 AND Finalpoint=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Attended FROM performance WHERE DATE(AssignDate) = CURDATE()```

Comment: are you still having issues with this question? what type of chart are you trying to draw?